# Ordering system on iPad based on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm planning an ordering system based on an `UITableView` for iPad. I'm subclassing `UITableViewCell` to show different `UILabel`, `UIButton` and `UITextfield` instances in a row.
But I've got a question: how to connect `UIButton` and `UITextField` instances together to know, which ones belong together?
The easiest idea (and I guess the worst one ;-)) would be to keep everything in a single class to maintain it somehow. But I would like to keep several classes because of the logical split (articles, shopping cart, categories ...). But my problem is - how to connect them? When I click the button to add a new item - how do I exactly know that it was the article with number 234233? I know it would be possible to work with a `tag` - but I need more items in a row that need to be tagged... And to modify them...

I hope someone can help =).
As always, thanks in between!

Comment: why cant you give same tag for the button, textfield and label in a cell?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about it, but as far as I know I can only access one item with special tag? Apart from the possibility -  would that REALLY a neat solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set up my row subclass so that when I set what needs to be displayed (text,images) I pass in the entire data object to the row and keep a reference to it. Then when a button is clicked I use the row as the target and I will have all the information I need available right there.

After that I call a method in the controller as that's usually where the action needs to be processed.

In some other cases I pass the indexPath to the row but this has caused me problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a base number for each type.
 say indexpath.row for UIbutton 
1000+indexpath.row for UILabel
2000+indexpath.row for UITextField

using this you can uniquely identify all elements.